# What is the best approach to build a real-time, turn-based iPhone game with Rails as backend?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, api, rest

So basically I want to build an iPhone game, which is real-time and turn-based, with a back-end implemented in Rails.

The game flow is like the following:

> Player A and Player B will queue for a match. Then the server will
>   match these 2 players into a match which is turn-based.
>
> When the match starts, Player A waits while Player B is entering his
>   action, and Player B waits while Player A entering his action.
>
> The game ends after 5 or 6 turns.

What I am planning is that to use "**Devise**" for user authentication, and a **RESTful API**. The iOS game client will keep sending request to the server and ask if the opponent has finish his/her moves or not.

Is this approach correct for this kind of application? As this is the first time I use Rails to build an app, I am not sure which approach should be used. And there are far too many libraries or tools to choose from.

And if I use a RESTful API, how can I send request like

- has_opponent (when queueing for a match)
- take_actions?actions={...} (submitting the user actions at the end of each turn)

Any good suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to the game-design aspects of the question, but as far as a RESTful API, you could try something like:

```
GET /available-opponents?ratingMin=XX&ratingMax=YY

POST /actions
{
    "userId": "bob",
    "gameId": 231,
    "actionType": "StingLikeABee",
    ...
}
```

The only verb in your URI should be the HTTP verb: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worthwhile investigating what GameCenter offers. There are a lot of resources for turn-based matches, and Apple is continuously expanding on this, and taking the heavy lifting out of your hands.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch.html